# Maven dependency compile error : package does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, beyondcompare3

Maven dependency compile error : package does not exist

I have maven parent project which has dependency with another child project's jar file.

Child's jar file is build and success. When building parent again, I got "package does not exist" error.

When I extract the jar file using 7-zip which is present in 'target' location, those packages and its files does exist. I extracted the jar file using 'jar command'as well, files are present. But, when I open the same jar file using Beyond compare 3, those packages are missing.

Somehow maven and Beyond compare unable to identify the packages or is it different problems with maven and beyond compare? I am not sure. After breaking head for two days, no clue about it.

I am using Eclipse Kepler IDE and there are no compilation errors in the project.

Below is the maven version

[image]

Below is the artifact code

```
<groupId>net.pi.run.cut</groupId>
    <artifactId>run.cut.receive.mba</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.3</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

and the dependency code

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.pi.run.cut</groupId>
            <artifactId>run.cut.receive.mba</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Old 7.8.1 version is working fine. Jar has all content.

Below is the img from beyond compare tool, where it doesn't identify the package and its files. P.S. I m necessarily scrapping the folder names with purpose.

[image]

Below is the image sample from 7-zip

[image]

All your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: First Eclipse Kepler is a little bit old...furthermore your Maven version is also a little bit old and apart from that you are writing about a child project? Does that mean you have a multi module build with a folder structure and you are trying to build in a child only? Are you building from command line or from inside Eclipse?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes. Its a bit of old versions. But, earlier project versions are running fine. ex:7.8.1. Child project is build successfully. Jar file is created. I included child jar in parent project. While compiling parent I m getting this error. I am building both in eclipse and in command line both giving same errors. Note: there is no compilation errors in eclipse.

Comment: A parent usually has no code nor dependencies cause it's packaging `pom`...

Comment: Yes. Parent project is of package war. There is a version mismatch in Mapforce project that cause this issue. It is rectified now. Thank you.